# Adding a 'mega menu' to my site without a plugin

Tags: menus

Can anyone suggest the best way to go about adding a 'mega menu' to my wordpress navigation without using a plugin?

The content in the mega menu itself does not need to be editable via the CMS HOWEVER does need to be active when the user hovers over a certain li in the main navigation.

I've looked on Google but everything is geared towards the plugin route, which I'd liek to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with a plugin?

Comment: Well I don't really see the point in adding a plugin when the contents of the mega dropdown do not need to be updateable via the admin system.

Comment: I've used the .load function in jQuery. Simply cannot get my head around extended the walker.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll just point out how you can insert the HTML of your mega dropdown menu, then it’s up to you to style and animate it.

Dig around in `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` to find different useful filters for modifying navigation menus created in the admin area. I chose for the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter which gets applied to each menu item separately. After the anchor tag has been created you have the possibility to insert more HTML before the closing list item.

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse63345_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4 );

function wpse63345_walker_nav_menu_start_el( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    // The mega dropdown only applies to the main navigation.
    // Your theme location name may be different, "main" is just something I tend to use.
    if ( 'main' !== $args->theme_location )
        return $item_output;

    // The mega dropdown needs to be added to one specific menu item.
    // I like to add a custom CSS class for that menu via the admin area.
    // You could also do an item ID check.
    if ( in_array( 'mega-dropdown', $item->classes ) ) {
        $item_output .= '<div class="mega-dropdown">Your custom HTML</div>';
    }

    return $item_output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can use the HTML version of [JQuery Mega DropDown Menu](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/)
In this case you must manage the menu items via code!

Comment: Is there no way of injecting the div via jQuery?

Comment: To clarify - I'd like the top level menu items to be editable via Wordpress HOWEVER the content of the div that I'd like to appear on hover of page-item-13, to be hardcoded / not editable.